# Changing Data Types within the CMV Map Service

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, configurable-map-viewer

Is it possible to format fields that appear in tables within the map service?

In the table results after a spatial query, date fields are converted to UTC rather than duplicating  the values from the original data (e.g., original data is "1/2/2017"; the table in the CMV shows "1/1/2017  6:00 p.m.").  Export.js was modified with a Date() function so the exported file has the correct date.  Also, a field that is a multi-digit integer value is appearing as a floating point with decimal places and commas (e.g., value:  123456,  table field: 123,456.000). This value is a code and isn't a decimal value.

Comment: What table widget(s) are you using?

Comment: Tables are defined in the \js\gis\dijit\Find.js code.  There is also an AttributesTable widget that doesn't have documentation.

Answer (score 0):

This is two separate questions it seems.

## formatting the attributes table

You can pass a `gridOptions` object in the tables object that can format columns fairly easily. See [this link](https://github.com/tmcgee/cmv-widgets/blob/master/config/searchWidget.js#L75-L89) for details on how this looks in context.

```
gridOptions: {
     columns: [{
          field: 'incidentnm',
          label: 'Name'
     },{
          field: 'inspdate',
          label: 'Inspected',
          width: 150,
          get: function (object) { // allow export as a proper date
               return getDateTime(object.inspdate);
          },
          formatter: formatDateTime
},
```

In the example, `formatDateTime` is a function that would format your date. FYI, the attributes table and other widgets have extensive documentation in their relevent repo: https://github.com/tmcgee/cmv-widgets#attributes-tables

## formatting the find widgets table.

This isn't as easy, since the widget hasn't received a lot of attention now that most people are using the Search widget that tmcgee has in the same repo. But its still possible if you modify the widget when the grid is created.

Somewhere around [these lines](https://github.com/cmv/cmv-app/blob/develop/viewer/js/gis/dijit/Find.js#L273-L278) you would have to do this:

```
this.resultsGrid = new Grid({
     selectionMode: this.selectionMode,
     cellNavigation: false,
     showHeader: true,
     store: this.resultsStore,
     columns: [{
        label: 'First Name',
        field: 'first'
    },
    {
        label: 'Last Name',
        field: 'last'
    },
    {
        label: 'Age',
        field: 'age',
        get: function(object){
            return (new Date() - object.birthDate) / 31536000000;
        }
    }]
}, this.findResultsGrid);
```